# Can I use JR Rail Pass for New Chitose Airport Limousine bus?

Tags: japan, buses, jr-passes

am currently in Sapporo, Japan and catching a flight early on Friday, 27 December. I am planning to either use the Airport Limousine Bus or the Rapid Airport to get to the airport. I also have a JR Rail Pass. Can I use the JR Rail Pass for the bus service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot, because the three bus companies serving CTS are Hokkaido Chuo Bus, Hokuto Kotsu, and Donan Bus. JR Hokkaido is not one of them, and apparently a JR pass will not work on non-JR transportation (note there are exceptions but none apply here).

Instead, what you *may* do is to use JR Hokkaido's "Express Airport" train which will take you to the airport from Sapporo station.